# What's the difference between mockk() and mockkClass()?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

When I started learning Mockk for testing, I had the following question.

[Mockk official sample](https://mockk.io/#dsl-examples) shows like:

```kotlin
val car = mockk<Car>()
```

and

```kotlin
val car = mockkClass(Car::class)
```

I seem the two as the same.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the first mock instantiation method takes a [type argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html), and the second takes a [class reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) KClass.

So in practice, those examples produce the same result, but I guess the second one has a higher degree of freedom to decouple the class being mocked during runtime.